# TFS 2017 Admin Getting Access Denied when installing gallery extensions

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

Recently my team upgraded to TFS 2017 from TFS 2012.  I am a TFS administrator on the box but when i attempt to install a gallery extension in a specific team project collection i get:

```
"Access Denied. {user} needs Manage permissions to perform the action.
For more information, contact the Team Foundation Server administrator."
```

that would be fine, except i am the server administrator...sigh.  the steps i have taken so far are:

- reapplied my Admin Console User access.
- confirmed i am still a member of the "Project Collection Administrators".
- made sure i was in the "Project Administrators" groups for all of the collections projects.
- made sure i had allow on "edit/view project-level information" for all projects.
- compared security rules between other team project collections and the issue collection.
- used TFSSecurity to directly set permissions again.

When i found that none of these steps worked i went so far as to ask another admin to remove me and add me back, to no avail.  i should also mention, i have the ability to add extensions in other team project collections, just not the main one we use for development.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

We found a [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10661/permission-problems-since-upgrading-to-tfs-2017.html) about there being a bug in the RTM version of tfs 2017, we were skeptical that is the cause as we had already done the potential workaround without success.  We have decided we are going to attempt to install update 1 to see if that resolves the issues.  I will update with the result, but that will not happen until the next maint window.

**UPDATE 2:**

We installed TFS 2017 U2RC2, and it did indeed resolve the issue.  I suspect that Update 1 was all the farther that would be needed, but there are a bunch of nice features with U2RC2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your issue it's possibility not related to that bug in RTM TFS2017. The bug is more related to the security ACEs for collection admins at the **team project level** and thus, collection admins were unable to access and administer some team project resources.

To narrow down your issue, you could try below ways:

- Use another Admin account to install the specific extension
- Use your account to add some other extension

If this is a issue only related to your account, there must be something wrong with the security ACES. Double check and compare the different  permission settings between your account and other admin's account. Check if you have any related deny permission under the project collection. In TFS deny trumps allow.

Moreover when you do the remove and  add back operation , there maybe some identity synchronization problem in TFS. Waiting for sometime, you could try  to install the gallery extension again.

Of course, you could also update your TFS server, which may do the trick. Suggest you directly update to [TFS2017 update2 RC2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2), which will be the last “big” feature release for TFS 2017. ***[Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2)***

Comment: Thank you for your response.  we did indeed attempt to have me install other extensions, none were successful.  two other admins attempted in the same team project collection with the same results.  it seems to be specific to that team project collection.  I remain mystified though as we have compared every setting between working collections and this one, with no visible differences.  I will definitely push update 2 RC 2.

Comment: @XBiLe To install extensions in TFS, you need to either belong to the Administrator group at TFS Server machine or in the TFS Administration Console Users. If all your admins lose security to this, I'm afraid there must something wrong with that specially team project collection. You could check if you are lacking some other permission as a Admin for  the collection. If you have the backup of it, you could try to detach the collection , restore database and attach the collection. If above is still not working, waiting for the upgrade to see if the issue solved. Good luck :)